# Why doesn't Grignard reagent attack alkyl halides

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, organometallic-compounds

When we add magnesium to
 alkyl halide, Grignard reagent is formed. $$\ce{R-X + Mg -> RMgX } $$ It is highly nucleophilic in nature.  Now at this time the electrophilic alkyl halide is also present in the solution why doesn't grignard reagent simply attack the alkyl halide again ?? $$\ce{ RMgX + R-X  -> R-R + MgX2}$$ Why doesn't this reaction take place ??

Comment: The above does contain the answer, although the question itself has a few more points.

Comment: Because what happens is mainly exchange between the initial Grignard and the alkyl halide. If you want coupling you need to add Cu(I), even then its not that good.

Comment: Alternatively, how is it possible to make a Grignard reagent if coupling is an issue?